# Mounting log file to some other location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have path where some log files are generated dynamically everyday with timestamp and `400 (-r--------)`  permission , so the owner of these files can view the logs.

Logs path : `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath`

Log files :

```
-r--------    LogFile_20141001
-r--------    LogFile_20141002
-r--------    LogFile_20141003
```

I want `others` to view the logs, but I can't give read permission to logs for `others` and copying the logs every-time to a location `(eg : /dir_02/logs)`  & giving permission there, so that `others` can see, is really difficult, as logs are created dynamically. Is there any way, that whenever the logs are created in actualy logs path i.e . `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath` , the same is updated on some other path like  `/dir_02/logs` with read permission to `others`. Is mounting will be helpful for this scenario, if so, then how.

Comment: Read about `umask` and set your directory permissions to how  you want the files to be permissioned.

Comment: I guess `umask` will set a definite permission for me, but I don't want to set that for my actual log path file `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath`, the `400` permission is fine. I want the logs files which are created on my actual log file path to be copied somehow to other path like `/dir_02/logs` with `read` permission for `others`, so that they can also view the logs. `Others` will have permission to go to `/dir_02/logs` path but not to actual log path `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to use umask option (for some of filesystems e.g vfat) during mouting, and then all files created in this dir will have required permissions, but definitively better option is to use extended acls, then all files created in dir(s) will have set up permission according to your requirements.

Umask syscall (not umask mount option) sets up permission but only for calling process. It means, that if another process which have another umask, creates file/dir - the permission will not appropriate to your requirements.

I can't get if these are the same files or not:

```
/dir_01/abc_01/logpath
/dir_02/logs
```

But if you want to do something exactly in the moment of creating a file, then you need notify to monitor dir (to catch a event) and execute another action when file is created.

Comment: I guess `umask` will set a definite permission for me, but I don't want to set that for my actual log path file `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath`, the `400` permission is fine. I want the logs files which are created on my actual log file path to be copied somehow to other path like `/dir_02/logs` with `read` permission for `others`, so that they can also view the logs. `Others` will have permission to go to `/dir_02/logs` path but not to actual log path `/dir_01/abc_01/logpath`

Comment: so I guess that you copy files from original location to another by external tool. Then I would recommended you using rsync with --chmod option, and then you can set up in chmod options permission whatever you want to dir and files.